# Is there support for validating (intellisense) inline CSS3 in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, css, intellisense

I am running Visual Studio 2010. I have installed SP1 and the Web Standards Update and restarted Visual Studio. I can now select CSS3 for validation and Intellisense of CSS files, but for "style" attributes of html elements, it is still using CSS 2.1. For example, the following html:

```
<div style="text-overflow:ellipsis;">
    Some text
</div>
```

produces the following warning:

> Validation (CSS 2.1): 'text-overflow' is not a known CSS property name

Things that I have tried that didn't work:

- Adding the CSS toolbar didn't help, because when viewing an .aspx page, the options are all greyed out
- The Options -> Text Editor -> CSS menu has no level options
- The Options -> Text Editor -> HTML menu has no CSS level options
- Changing the HTML target schema to HTML5 does not change the CSS level
- Installing CSS3 IS 2.1.1 didn't change anything

Is there any way to get Visual Studio to use CSS3 for the style attributes of HTML elements?

Comment: i usually ignore warnings about CSS from VS.

Comment: It looks like you may have found a bug!

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Extension manager 
Then search for Css 3 (online gallery), install.
I'm not sure this will work, but its worth a try.